# Call Databricks API from DevOps Pipeline using Service principal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to be able to call Databricks API from DevOps pipeline. I can do this usint personal access token for my account, however I want to make API calls user independent so I wanted to use Service principal (App registration). I followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token to create access token for the service principal, however I have 2 issues:

1. such generated token expires in 1 hour - is there any elegant was to automatically refresh it?
2. even when calling the ADB API using this token I get 403 unauthorized - is there anything else I should do? The app registration has Contributor role for the ADB service.

EDIT: Added API Permission for the AzureDatabricks in App registration and Granted admin consent, however still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found 3 possible solutions at the end.

1. Generate access token for service principal, generate management service token for service principal and use both of these to access Databricks API - [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token#--api-access-for-service-principals-that-are-not-workspace-users)
2. Use access token and management token to generate Databricks Personal access token for the service principal using Databricks Token API, then you can use it for Databricks CLI - [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/tokens)
3. Authenticate to Databricks via CLI using AAD token ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/#--set-up-authentication-using-an-azure-ad-token) and Databricks CLI help):

   1. `az login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <app-password> --tenant <tenant-id>`
   2. `token_response=$(az account get-access-token --resource 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d)`
   3. `export DATABRICKS_AAD_TOKEN=$(jq .accessToken -r <<< "$token_response")`
   4. `databricks configure --host https://<adb-url> --aad-token`

Comment: Databricks CLI v0.214.0: "Unknown flag '--aad-token'"

Comment: @Krumelur you just directly pipe the token to the configure command as it now support both AAD and Databricks. `databricks configure --host https://asd.com/ <<< "token"`

Answer (score 1):

> 1. such generated token expires in 1 hour - is there any elegant was to
>    automatically refresh it?

No, [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) doesn't support refresh token. You can try to get a new token, please refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42027517/13308381).

> 2. even when calling the ADB API using this token I get 403 unauthorized - is there anything else I should do? The app
>    registration has User role for the ADB service.

Make sure your service principal have a Contributor role assigned.

There are two kinds of resource in different situations.

1. API access for service principals that are Azure Databricks workspace users and admins

   `resource=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d`
2. API access for service principals that are not workspace users

   `resource=https://management.core.windows.net/`

Comment: Thank you for you reply. When I use `resource=2ff..` I get `Error 403 User not authorized.` when used with ADB API. When I use `resource=https:..` I get `Error 400 io.jsonwebtoken.IncorrectClaimException: Expected aud claim to be: 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d`. I also checked IAM for ADB service and the service principal has Contributor role. Any idea why is that?

Comment: Did you add Azure Databricks permission in "API Permissions"? Please navigate to API Permissions -> add a permission -> API my organization uses -> search "AzureDatabricks"  and add it. Then click grant admin consent.

Comment: still 403 Unauthorized :(

Comment: Could you let me know the specific API you are calling?

Comment: Tried list clusters 2.0/clusters/list and jobs run-now. None of them working.

Comment: So, finally, I used management endpoint access token to access the Databricks REST API and now it works, BUT only from my local machine... Not from the DevOps agent.. I already tried microsoft-hosted one as well as self-hosted.. I am getting `Error 400 io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature.`